# Generate Next Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

I was given this question about generating fib numbers. The recursive implementation of fib numbers which I've seen were always from top to previous like fib(n)=fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) but this question is assuming fib(n-1), fib(n-2) exist calculate next and so forth.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    int[] fiboNums;

    public Fibonacci(int n) {
        // TODO: generate the first n fibonacci numbers
    }

    private void generateNextFibo(int n, int lastFibo, int lastLastFibo) {
        // TODO: Implement this recursive function to compute next
        // fibonacci number.
    }

    public int[] getAll() {
        return  fiboNums;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you asking a question that you already know the answer too...

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz asking questions to answer them is perfectly fine.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz have u ever created a question in SO? if u've ever noticed there's a checkbox at the bottom which indicates u can answer yr question.

Comment: why recursion? there are other methods that don't involve recursion

Comment: @assembler just for challenging

Comment: ok, I see your point

Comment: `just for challenging`: `int[] getAll()` looks as challenging as it gets.

Comment: @greybeard are u familiar with "TODO"? focus on that part, u'll see the challenge

Answer (score 3):

The first tricky part is with what passing params generateNextFibo needs to be called. the second part is the exit condition of generateNextFibo method.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    int fiboNums[];

    public Fibonacci(int n) {
        // generate the first n fibonacci numbers
        fiboNums = new int[n];
        fiboNums[0] = 1;
        fiboNums[1] = 1;

        // Start from 3 since the first two fibo numbers are given
        if (n >= 3)
            generateNextFibo(3, fiboNums[1], fiboNums[0]);
    }

    private void generateNextFibo(int n, int lastFibo, int lastLastFibo) {
        // Implement this recursive function to compute next fibo number.
        fiboNums[n - 1] = lastFibo + lastLastFibo;
        if (fiboNums.length > n) {
            lastLastFibo = lastFibo;
            lastFibo = fiboNums[n - 1];
            generateNextFibo(n + 1, lastFibo, lastLastFibo);
        }
    }

    public int[] getAll() {
        return  fiboNums;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now if there were [doc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide), readers could check in how far the specification is met.

Comment: @greybeard see it as pseudo code or legacy code if it helps. Any new solution u can come up with? :)

Comment: `Any new solution [a greybeard] can come up with?` No. Greybeards know *everything* (worth mentioning) has been said and done, if not by everyone.